# android translateAnimation

Tags: android, view, translate-animation

If I have two views, is it possible to create in a view a translate animation and even if the object moves outside his view, the view's height and width remain unchanged? I need to show moving object only inside his view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View Animations on a view are always clipped to the parent view - it is common to translate by +/- 100% to ensure the view is moved completely out of the parent and works well without the view overdrawing any other aspect of the screen.

Comment: you are right. I've added  android:layout_marginBottom="35dp" to my view and that's why it moved all of my items below it. Thanks